# How to install Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

Now we're developing our software on the customer side, and there is:

```
maestro@UIServer:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=9.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=karmic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 9.10"
```

system is installed. We're not allowed to upgrade this system to a newer version, but we need to use Python 2.7 in our project.

E.g. we have to use pymorphy2 package, but when we're trying to import it into project, we get:

```
>>> import pymorphy2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymorphy2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .analyzer import MorphAnalyzer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymorphy2/analyzer.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pymorphy2 import opencorpora_dict
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymorphy2/opencorpora_dict/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .storage import load_dict as load
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymorphy2/opencorpora_dict/storage.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pymorphy2.utils import json_write, json_read
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymorphy2/utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    import bz2
ImportError: No module named bz2
```

Ok, we're trying to install libbz2-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
```

end getting this:

```
ValueError: /usr/bin/python does not match the python default version. It must be reset to point to python2.6
dpkg: error processing python-pip (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pip
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How to avoid this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you add old-releases.ubuntu.com repository to your sources.list?

Comment: Yes, deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted

Answer (score 1):

Download [python](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.9/Python-2.7.9.tgz), build and install using :

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

I am assuming you have `build-essential` installed or at least `gcc`. You can customize installation by passing `prefix=/path/where/you/want/python/installed` and other flags to `make`.

Comment: In my case, I assume, I need to build it into /usr/bin, right? How many links do I have to change in FS in order to change the version of python?

Comment: By defalut prefix is `/usr/bin`. Make sure you run `make install` as superuser or `sudo make install` since not everyone has write permission to `/usr/bin`.

Comment: If things go wrong and my build will crash on this new version, how can I roll back the previous version of python?

Comment: I would advice not to erase the Python installation that come with Ubuntu, because it could break other things in system, but instead install it *elsewhere*, for example under `/usr/local` or `/opt`

Comment: @SergeBallesta, and what should I change in this case in system environment in order to point to a new version of python by default?

Comment: @paus : I wouldn't dare changing anything in *system environment*, precisely to avoid breaking anything else. If possible, I would use full path to call the new Python interpreter, or at least I would only change the `PATH` environment variable for the only applications that need it, putting the folder where new python resider **before** `/usr/bin`